# Describe the cosets

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

$G$ is a cyclic group. $H$ is a subgroup of $G$. $|G|=12$, $|H|=3$. Why the sets of left and right cosets is a $H$, $xH$, $x^2H$, $x^3H$?

Comment: What is $x$? Any $x$? A generator of $G$?

Comment: @lhf, yes, $x$ is a generator of $G$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $G$ is cyclic, then it is generated by a single element, $x$, so $G = \{1, x, x^2, \dots, x^{11}\}$. Since $|G| = 12$, we know that $x^{12} = 1$. Furthermore, $H$ is a subgroup of order $3$, so it must contain the identity and exactly $3$ elements. So it must be true that $H = \{1, x^4, x^8\}$. (Why?) Furthermore, by the counting formula, we know that there are $4$ cosets, and the cosets partition the group. At this point, it's easy to see that $H, xH, x^2 H, x^3 H$ partition the group, and there are $4$ of them, so these must be the cosets.

Answer (score 0):

$H$ has index $12/3=4$ and so, given any $g \in G$, the set $\{ g^k H : k \in \mathbb N \}$ has at most four elements.

It is easy to see that $\{ g^k H : k \in \mathbb N \} =\{ H, gH, g^2H, g^3H \}$. However, this latter set may have less than four elements: take for instance $g=e$. It all depends on the smallest $k$ such that $g^k \in H$.